# lme4 - nested time structure

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a group of participants that performed measurements in 9 session. We performed 3 measurements per session of the same variable. Normally we would average these 3 measurements and call it a day, but I thought it would be nice to use this in the model. For the 9 sessions it would have looked something like this:

```
full_model <- lmer(outcome ~ nsession + (1 + nsession|participant), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

I could do the same thing with the individual measurements (1-27) and replace 'session' with 'measurement', but they are not quite independent because they were sampled in the same session. Instead, I tried something like this:

```
full_model <- lmer(outcome ~ nmeasurement + (1 + nmeasurement|participant) + (1 + nmeasurement|nsession), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

However, I do not believe this returns the correct coefficients. Across sessions the slope should be positive and within sessions it was negative for this particular variable, however, if I correct it like this the slope for measurement is negative. This is not really what I'm interested in.

So the final thing I came up with was:

```
full_model <- lmer(outcome ~ nsession + (1 + nsession|participant) + (1 + nmeasurement|session), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

This kinda made sense to me as session (1-9) is nested within participant and measurement (1-3) is nested within session. The coefficients seem plausible to me, but is the model legit?

OK, this also seems to give reasonable coefficients:

```
full_model <- lmer(outcome ~ncmeasurement + (1 + ncmeasurement|participant) + (1 + nmeasurement|session), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

Where ncmeasurement is 1-27 and nmeasurement is 1-3. I'm even more confused now..

Comment: This isn't clear. Explain the variables?

Comment: OK, so let's say we measure strength in 9 consecutive weeks. Each time someone comes in we measure strength three times. Normally we would average this and that would make the result more reliable. However, I thought it would be better if we could include all data. In that case, I would need to account for the nested structure of the measurements. I'm expecting someone to improve over the 9 weeks, but I also expect that within the 3 measurements someone perform worse (due to fatigue).